# How can I get a Unique Value for a SharePoint Client Web Part?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-addin, app

I would like to get the App part Id so i can uniquely identify what app part is calling my code. I can do that with the normal web parts but I don't know how to get it from the client side code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a propetry that you can get automaticlly in the elements.xml called WPID that you can pass to your aspx page.

```
<Content Type="html" Src="~appWebUrl/Pages/Default.aspx?{StandardTokens}&amp;wpId=_WPID_" />
```